# Scraping with Selenium. No such element: Unable to locate element because of loop?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to access each name in the page and then scrape the HTML code. Since there are multiple pages I tried to use a loop. Each "line" I want to access has the same xpath; the only thing that changes is a number in it.
When I try to run the code I get `No such element: Unable to locate element`. Is it because str(x) does not fit in the xpath?

```
import time
import os 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import glob 
import re 
import shutil

def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try: 
       driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
       return False
    return True  

base_url =r"https://threedecks.org/index.php?display_type=crewman_search"

path_driver = r"C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver)    
driver.get(base_url)

pic_path0="//*[@id=\"nation\"]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(pic_path0).send_keys('Great Britain')
time.sleep(1)
pic_path1="//*[@id=\"roles\"]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(pic_path1).send_keys('Sailor')
pic_path2="//*[@id=\"form_row_Search\"]/input"  
driver.find_element_by_xpath(pic_path2).click()

for x in xrange(0,51):
    pic_path3="//*[@id=\"crew_search_results\"]/tbody/tr[" + str(x)
    +"]/td[2]/a"

    driver.find_element_by_xpath(pic_path3).click()
    info=get_attribute("href")
    time.sleep(1)

    scraped = open('C:\Users\emarchesi\Desktop\links.txt',"wt")
    scraped.write(info)
    scraped.close()
```

Comment: I am unable to understand your code completely. The `str(x)` should work. You could print `pic_path3` and test it in your browser manually, by using the Firebug addon... By doing so, you can check if your x-path is correct.

Comment: Post complete exception with stack trace